# How can I restore /usr/share/fonts on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, fonts, restore

I did something extremely stupid.
I'm currently working on a 10.04 system (work-related), and since I was missing some fonts I decided to simply copy some over from my own, 12.10 system. I ran

cp -R <12.10 root>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/* /usr/share/fonts/truetype/

Immediately, terminal and window header fonts got completely messed up, although chromium still shows everything correctly, as does nautilus.

How can I restore this directory? Is there anything else I have do afterwards?

[image]

Comment: did you try launch this command ? fc-cache -fv

Comment: It completes with "fc-cache: succeeded". Nothing changes.

Comment: Here is the full output: http://pastebin.pw/y8r46n

Comment: Glad you got if fixed but `gnome-session-save -` suggests it is a desktop system and 10.04 desktop is end of life ;)

Comment: I know - it's just one computer that many people have used over the years, so everybody is scared of the system getting broken for when they might need it again. But I faintly remember doing the update manager doing a distro upgrade a while ago - what does that actually change, what does it leave put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to add how this was resolved: Simply restarting X using

```
gnome-session-save --force-logout
```

(from an X terminal), next login everything was Ok again.